# How to persist a collection of interface's Collection<Interface> in JPA?

Tags: collections, jpa, interface, persistence

I have an the following scenario:

```
// several classes that implement different interfaces 
class A implements X,Y {}
class B implements Y,Z {}
class C implements X,Z {}

// other classes that contain collections of one of the interfaces(different objects)
class G {
  Collection<X> mayContainAC;
}
class H {
  Collection<Y> mayContainAB;
}
class I {
  Collection<Z> mayContainBC;
}
```

How would I go about persisting this using JPA?

From what I can see JPA doesn't support Collections of interfaces. Is the correct?
JDO does support it but I am having difficulties getting JDO to place nicely with my Wicket app.

Thanks, Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would I go about persisting this using JPA?

Not supported.

> From what I can see JPA doesn't support Collections of interfaces. Is the correct?

If the interface has a single persistent implementer, then you can define it using the `targetEntity`.

If the interface has multiple implementers, it's not supported by standard JPA.

Comment: thanks for confirmation - whats the recommended workaround for the scenario I have described?

Comment: @Tom You could maybe persist separated collections and merge them yourself.

Comment: I considered that but I need order of the mixed items and I will need to add different types over time. I think I'll have to go with an abstract base class and restrict what can go in each some other way. I wonder if using Scala classes & Traits could help solve this?

Comment: Pascal, congratulations on passing the 100K reputation mark.  Most impressive.

Comment: @Tom A common abstract class is the traditional approach. I'm not *sure* Scala or anything else could help.

Comment: I guess one way would be to have abstract base classes called, ThingsThatGoInG, ThingsThatGoInH and ThingsThatGoInI and then some container classes; AinG class that has-a A as a property, BinG class that has-a B as a property, BinH that has-a B property etc. Lots of extra classes but allows for flexible grouping and follows the open/closed priniple better. You would have one level of indirection to reach the actual class and it would have more complicated JOINs but wouldnt rely on UNIONs.

Comment: @Tom The inheritance + composition approach that you are describing should do it.

Answer (score 0):

> JDO does support it

Yes JDO does support persistent interfaces and we've been using them since 2007 in all of our designs because, you know, using interfaces in Java programming is like object oriented modeling 1.0.1. If your ORM doesn't support them then your so called 'transparent persistence' solution is actually not very transparent.

This and some other short comings have meant we have steered clear of the most popular JPA implementation and ended up using an ORM something slightly less popular but much more powerful and highly productive when it comes to object oriented modeling. We use DataNucleus/JDO where persistent interfaces work perfectly. I can't imagine building OO models without this support.

I'm not sure what the inherent architectural limitation is with the most popular JPA implementation that it can't support persistent interfaces.

As well as implementing the JDO standard DataNucleus also implements the JPA standard. There is a chance that DataNucleus/JPA does support persistent interfaces but I've only ever used DataNucleus with JDO so I don't know for sure.

> but I am having difficulties getting JDO to place nicely with my Wicket app.

We have a massive (400+ persistent classes) web application/cloud platform deployed using JDO with the (most excellent) Wicket java UI framework and have never had a problem. We have created a couple of JDO specific IModel implementations that work with Wicket's model binding architecture. Let us know if you want to use these and we can open source them.